# Confusion related to P and NP problems

Tags: algorithms

I have this confusion related to P and NP problems. Why is P a subset of NP? I didn't get it. P problems can be solved in polynomial time. However, NP problems cannot but only verify if a solution is correct of not in polynomial time. Then how come P is subset of NP?

Answer (score 9):

The flaw in your thinking is this statement: "NP problems cannot [be solved in polynomial time]". In other words, you seem to be under the impression that NP is an *opposite* of P. This is not correct.

Class NP contains all problems whose solutions can be *verified* or *checked* in polynomial time---but it places no conditions on how difficult the problem is to *solve*. That is, the standards for Class NP are *easier* to meet than for Class P.

Honestly, the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem) on the topic provides a relatively decent overview of the matter. The example of a problem in NP that they give is the "subset sum problem":

> Consider the subset sum problem, an example of a problem that is easy
>   to verify, but whose answer may be difficult to compute. Given a set
>   of integers, does some nonempty subset of them sum to 0? For instance,
>   does a subset of the set {−2, −3, 15, 14, 7, −10} add up to 0? The
>   answer "yes, because {−2, −3, −10, 15} add up to zero" can be quickly
>   verified with three additions. However, there is no known algorithm to
>   find such a subset in polynomial time (there is one, however, in
>   exponential time, which consists of $2^n-1$ tries), and indeed such an
>   algorithm can only exist if P = NP; hence this problem is in NP
>   (quickly checkable) but not necessarily in P (quickly solvable).

If you are given a very large set of integers, finding a non-empty subset that adds up to zero is extremely expensive; but given a single *potential* solution, verifying that it is a valid solution is quite trivial.